# How do I prevent a user delete?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I see that in Firebase deleting a user is very easy, but in my case I would like to prevent its cancellation so that the user can delete only his data in the database.

Why? Because if I maintain his uid and email, I’m sure that if this user wants to re-register with the same email, he will want to reuse the same data. In the case of old data that has not been purged, the result will be nearly the same without having to create another uid but with the risk of having dead account data lingering in the database.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as you use the word "data" to mean different things. What exactly do you want to do?